# How do I stop my main body overlapping my navbar and banner in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm currently designing a website and am having some trouble with my nav bar and header. I have coded the CSS so that the Nav bar and banner image stay at the top of the page when scrolling.

This is succesful, however the text from the body goes up past the navbar. I have set all margins and padding around the nav bar. Is there a way I can set it up so that the banner, nav bar and main body all follow as one?
The main body text is obviously an example, and obviously page links are not filled in yet etc.

To see an example of what is happening. Go here: www.jamiewebguy.com

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">



<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Jamie. The Web Guy</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homep.css">

</head>



<body>

<header>

<span class="banner_h">
<img src="Exbanner.jpg" alt "Banner" height="150" width= 100%/>
</span>

<p><ul>

  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>

  <li><a href="#news">What?</a></li>

  <li><a href="#contact">Pricing</a></li>

  <li><a href="#about">Contact Us</a></li>

<li><a href="#about">Testimonials</a></li>

<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>

</header>

</ul></p>
<div id="main-content">
        <h1>Some Heading</h1>
        <p>Some Text</p>
    <div>A div</div>


<h1>Some Heading</h1>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <div>A div</div>
 <h1>Some Heading</h1>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <div>A div</div>
 <h1>Some Heading</h1>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <div>A div</div>
 <h1>Some Heading</h1>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <div>A div</div>
 <h1>Some Heading</h1>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <div>A div</div>
 <h1>Some Heading</h1>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <div>A div</div>
 <h1>Some Heading</h1>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <div>A div</div>
 <h1>Some Heading</h1>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <div>A div</div>
 <h1>Some Heading</h1>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <div>A div</div>
    </div> 


</body>
```

CSS Code:

```
header {
        position:fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
}

ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center; 
}

li {
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;

}

li:last-child {

}

li a 
{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

li a:hover 
{

    background-color: #111;
}
.active 
{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}


#main-content 
{
 margin: 300px 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

You can define the background of the header so the content still scrolls underneath, but you won't see it:

```
header: background-color: white
```

You could also put the main text div inside a fixed position div with `overflow` set to scroll. This will keep it in place and your content will scroll off the top of it instead of the page:

```
<div id="container"> 
    <div id="main-content">
```

With css:

```
#container {
   top: 230px;
   bottom:0; 
   width: 100%; 
   position: fixed; 
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The first solution worked a treat. However the second solution just caused the body text to go OVER the header. (Well, it didnt move at all but i changed the position to relative.)

Answer (score 1):

Your html is wrong. You have `<img src="Exbanner.jpg" alt "Banner" height="150" width= 100%/>` 
you need to have `<img src="Exbanner.jpg" alt="Banner" height="150px" width= "100%"/>`
then you have `</header>` but there is no opening `<header>` above anywhere

that also messes up the `<ul> <li>` menu

Comment: Thank you, have changed the banner HTML. However, yes there is an opening header by the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Give the header and the unordered list relative positions instead of fixed:

```
 header {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
}

ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}
```

Comment: When I do that they scroll up with the page, and I wanted them to stay on top of the page when I scrolled down.